# How to insert spaces between certain groups in a ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just made this graph

[image]

Using this set of data

| G | T |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 4 | 17 |
| 4 | 18 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 4 | 18 |
| 4 | 18 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 4 | 17 |
| 4 | 17 |
| 4 | 19 |
| 4 | 19 |

And this code:

```
ggplot(Raiz, aes(x = G, y = T, 
                 color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 1, size =3) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(color = '')
```

I would like to know how can I put spaces between the pairs of measurements of each treatment. For example: 1,2 - space - 3,4 .... Not a big space, but enough to easily differentiate treatments.

Comment: Add a variable for the pairs, then facet on that

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes in image using.

Can you please help me on hot to add a variable for the pairs and then facet on that? I'm a begginer. If you could help me using the code that I gave I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(ggplot2)

Raiz <- data.frame(G = rep(seq(1:6), each = 10),
                   T = sample.int(20, 60, replace = T))


ggplot(Raiz, aes(x = as.factor(G), y = T, 
                 color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)], 
                 group = G)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 1, size =3) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  facet_wrap(~(G-1) %/% 2, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(color = '', x = "G")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `facet_wrap` with `scale = free_x`. For this we add a new column to the data frame with two groups:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Raiz %>% 
  mutate(supergroup = ifelse(G %in% c(1,2), "one", "two")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(G), y = T, 
                   color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 0.5, size =4) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2,
             position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue3", "red3"))+
  facet_wrap(.~supergroup, scales = "free_x", labeller = labeller(supergroup = function(x) ""))+
  labs(x="")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(color = '')+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14))

tar_ggplot_font_size()
```

data:

```
structure(list(G = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), T = c(7L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 16L, 17L, 
19L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 18L, 
16L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-56L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit of modular math and faking the x axis:

```r
ggplot(within(Raiz, x <- G + (G - 1) %/% 2 * 0.4),
       aes(x = x, y = T, 
           color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 1, size =3) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.75, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9), aes(group = G)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6 + 0:5 %/% 2 * 0.4,
                     labels = floor) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(color = '')
```

[image]